# Best way to get users location in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, location, maps

I have tried `FusedLocationAPI`, however, the accuracy it returns is too high as compared to `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`, so the result is as follows, where the Blue circle is plotted by `setMyLocationEnabled` and the Black one is the accuracy as plotted by `FusedLocationAPI`.

[image]

I also used this piece of code

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (myLocation == null) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
}

LatLng myPos = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPos).title("Start"));
```

But the marker plotted is again, too far away from he `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` like this
[image]

So I was wondering if there was a better way to get location more accurately?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **ACCURACY_FINE** instead of **ACCURACY_COARSE** in your `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);` Hope that helps.